# python reading csv, text inside comma inside a column having double double inverted comma "" text,text2 ""causing split with the comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, double-quotes

Well I have been sent a csv by othe system with comma as the delimiter. one row has one column with sample values as: 
,""ABC. & XYZ (CfdfB,afGgM)_0110"" , .
This row cause of this column is causing error.
While debugging Now when I read this using python and printed row, this particular value is printed as: 
'ABC. & XYZ (CfdfB', ' afGgM)_0110""'
so this valus is getting split, reason being double of " and a comma in between.

code used is:

```
    with open(abccsv, "r",  newline='',encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        # counter = 0
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different delimiter than comma. It's splitting because it's using comma as it's delimiter for CSV files. Try tab or something else.

Comment: ofcourse it's not my csv, its provided by someone else... so I dont have control over it.

Comment: , comma is the delimiter of this csv, how can I use any other delimiter.
My code is reading an csv sent by other system, and not creating the csv, hence the delimiter must be ,
I am able to read all lines of the csv fine, only cause of this one line reading a row is failing, which I am catching in try catch block and bypassing for now.

Comment: reader = csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

Comment: Change where it says delimiter: reader = csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)